# Easy circuit for "nested" triggering

Tags: integrated-circuit, clock, pulse

I need a trigger circuit that gives several high pulses for an "out_0". After 5-6 pulses from out_0, it then gives one high pulse for an "out_1".

I don't need any circuit that's large or has high component count... so 555 ICs in astable mode or microcontrollers are kind of a no, no...

I'm sure there's a special IC out there that only needs a single resistor and/or a capacitor to set the timings AND can do the triggering in a "looped" or "nested" way... and, if it's also very rare I could always order it online.

EDIT:
by a "single resistor/capacitor", i mean just one every nest.

Comment: Microcontroller != high component count.  Something like the PIC 10F series seems eminently suitable.  6 pins, tiny, built in oscillator, no support components needed except maybe a single bypass cap.

Comment: Also, it'd be a lot easier to understand your question with a diagram of your desired input and output waveforms.

Comment: This sounds like a counter circuit that can be implemented with flip flops and gate logic, but if your goal is to be tiny you simply must take another look at microcontrollers. Really. See all the comments and answers telling you so.

Answer (score 1):

Despite your "no MCU's" desire the obvious answer is a low pin-count example like a PIC10F or 12F.  Around 5sqmm of PCB space for a SOT23-6 case and an 0402 cap is all you would need.